# Who portrayed the Rakshasa in the 1974 television series Kolchak: The Night Stalker?

Tags: actor-identification, kolchak-the-night-stalker

The TV series Kolchak: The Night Stalker, which followed the monster-fighting adventures of small-time newspaper reporter Carl Kolchak (played by Darren McGavin) had an episode featuring a Hindu demon called a Rakshasa.

The Rakshasa(s) were cannibal demons who had been banished from Earth long ago. Periodically the creatures sent an agent back to Earth to learn if humanity had grown weak enough to be conquered.

The Night Stalker was a short run series that ended after only twenty episodes. The Rakshasa episode, 'The Horror in the Heights', is episode eleven.
The show's monsters were mostly portrayed by uncredited actors. I have been able to identify most of the players, but not the Rakshasa.

[image]

Comment: The Nightstalker wiki at https://nightstalker.fandom.com/wiki/Horror_in_the_Heights#Cast says "Despite false rumors that the Rakshasha was portrayed by Richard Kiel, the uncredited actor has never been identified by any official source."

Comment: Mr. Clean? Famous actor and lifeguard Duke Fishman portrayed a passerby in the episode. He could have served as the monster. Just saying.

Comment: @SamAzon: IMDb has the same information: "Some news articles and magazines have stated that Richard Kiel played the Raksasha, although he did not. The uncredited actor has not been identified by any official source." https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0621537/trivia/?ref_=tt_trv_trv

Comment: The IMDB page lists stunts and a  stand-in, who might have done this. I don't know if the monster was involved in any stunts, but if so it would have made sense to have the same stunt-man do all the monster work.